# registerIdlingResources deprecation replacement doesn't work

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to replace my Espresso `registerIdlingResources` and `unregisterIdlingResources` deprecated method by using `IdlingRegistry` method according to Android documentation.

Some of my tests worked before the update and no longer work now. These tests work unitarily, but not together.

I noticed that there is a little difference with the old version (of `Espresso` class), this line is not present in `IdlingRegistry` class :

```
baseRegistry.sync(IdlingRegistry.getInstance().getResources(), IdlingRegistry.getInstance().getLoopers());
```

I think this `sync` method is very important for my custom IdlingResource...

How can I sync my looper without this line?

Edit: I use EspressoCore 3.0.1 with runner/rules 1.0.1

Edit2: Link of documentation who has been specify deprecation : [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.html#registerIdlingResources(android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource...)) and [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.html#unregisterIdlingResources(android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource...)).

Answer (score 1):

##### 1. [*Android Test Orchestrator.*](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests/androidx-test-libraries/runner)

Android Test Orchestrator resolves your issue with `IdlingResources` test fails.

```
dependencies {
  androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.3.0'
}
```

**Configure your `build.gradle`:**

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true' 
 }
 testOptions {
   execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
 }
}
```

**Then run your tests:**

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

##### 2. [*Refactor the code*](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application-development/9781785286186/1/ch01lvl1sec13/refactoring-your-code)

The issue [`IdlingResources`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource) cause tests to fail. Refactoring solves such problems.

- Use [`Thread.sleep()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread) instead of [`IdlingResources`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/IdlingResource), I personally don't recommend in High Level Programming but it is fixes the problem.
- Modify the code with [`Callbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/security/auth/callback/Callback) & `Hooks`.
- Simplify the code without many and complex dependencies.

##### 3. Use [*Deprecated Methods.*](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated)

[`registerIdlingResources`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078005/why-is-espressos-registeridlingresources-deprecated-and-what-replaces-it) and [`unregisterIdlingResources`](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.support.test.espresso.Espresso/unregisterIdlingResources) Deprecated Methods are working in this context. Note that these methods need updates in the future versions of [`Espresso`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso).

##### 4. Use [*Third-party Testing Library*](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests).

I would give a try also with [`Robolectric`](https://robolectric.org) or [`Appium`](https://appium.io). They can give good guidance to handle [`IdlingResources`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-testing-with-espressos-idling-resources-and-testing-fidelity-8b8647ed57f4), along with performance benefits around testing environments.

##### 5. Upgrade to latest [`Espresso`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso) library:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

##### 6. Define [`IdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource):

```
 private val idlingResource = CountingIdlingResource("idlingResource")
```

##### 7. Register [`IdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource):

```
 IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(idlingResource)
```

##### 8. Unregister [`IdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource):

```
 IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingResource)
```

##### 9. Synchronize the [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper):

```
Handler(Looper ... ()).Delayed({

    // Your code

}, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to run the [latest version of `androidx.test`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/test)

If your tests run one at a time, but fail when run together, [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator) ("ATO") can solve that problem.
ATO runs each test method in a new process, so any in memory state is cleared.

[From the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator), the basic gradle setup is:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
   // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
   // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
  androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.3.0'
}
```

The docs also include setup for installing and using [Android Test Orchestrator without gradle](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-command-line).

You can also use ATO on Firebase Test Lab:

- [via web UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/instrumentation-test#enable_orchestrator)
- [via CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--use-orchestrator)

If you still have problems with your IdlingResources you can try the [busybee library](https://github.com/americanexpress/busybee) which simplifies using IdlingResources and makes them easier to debug.
(disclaimer, I am a maintainer of that library)