# Why is Espresso's registerIdlingResources deprecated, and what replaces it?

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm working on UI tests with Espresso for Android, and following the Google's [code sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/IdlingResourceSample/ChangeTextBehaviorTest.java) it is used, even though it's deprecated. So my questions are:

- why is it deprecated?
- what replaces it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I'm working on unit tests with Espresso

I hope you mean UI tests ;)

> why is it deprecated?

Some apps use build flavors in Gradle or a dependency injection framework, like Dagger, to generate test build configurations that register idling resources. Others simply expose the idling resource through their activities. The problem with all these approaches is that they add complexity to your development workflow, and some of them even break encapsulation.

> what replaces it?

Now you need to use [IdlingRegistry API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingRegistry.html)

Source: [Android Testing Support Library 1.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/android-testing-support-library-10-is.html)

Comment: Yes, you're right, UI tests ;) Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 27):

Since the example has not been updated, if you are using Espresso 3.0< instead of registerIdlingResources

```
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
```

you should use [IdlingRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingRegistry):

```
IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(mIdlingResource);
```